# Why does my wampp looks like this

Tags: wamp, wamp64

[image: wamp image]

It's not the same as I see in my tutorial so I'm quite confused on how to access them

EDIT: I want to access apache but there is no folder that shows apache in my image

Comment: Hmm? Look for its directory in Program Files

Comment: Thanks i found it, it was in the bin directory.

Comment: That can be anything. Different version, OS, config, etc.

Comment: WAMPServer has had some nice new features added recently. Most WAMPServer tutorials are old and many are next to useless